# Search across all sites from hub sub site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern, hub-site

I have a hub site with 3 sub sites. From the main hub site, Search returns results from all hub sites. Searches in a sub-site returns results only from that site.

How can I configure the Search in a sub-site to return results from all sites that are part of the hub?

Also, how could I have results from the whole instance?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, search in modern sites is not configurable. So,

- **Option 1** is to train users to click the breadcrumb on the search page to get to the broader results.
- **Option 2** is to create a custom spfx search box that redirects to the results page with the desired scope.
- **Option 3** is to redirect users to a classic search center, configured as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Option 1 is the way we a going.